# Validação com Phonegap e WebService

Tags: jquery, web-service, apache-cordova

estou validando os campos de login e senha via Web Services,ele me retorna se o login é valido e gera um numero de cookie(feito via sql),até aqui tudo bem ,consigo realizar validação normal mas me surgiu a seguinte duvida(dei uma boa olhada na internet sobre validação com cookie usando jquery),como faço para o meu sistema validar esse valor que vem via WEBSERVICE e se o usuario ja tiver feito o login uma vez e precisar fechar o aplicativo,ele continua com suas credenciais validas.

Até o momento meu codigo esta assim (tentei usar o $cookie para gravar o valor):

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST'
                //Caminho do WebService + / + nome do metodo
                , url: "http://localhost:11078/wsLogin.asmx/Login"
                , crossDomain: true
                , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                , dataType: 'json'
                //Abaixo adicione as variáveis caso haja alguma.
                , data: "{chave:'" + email + "', senha:'" + senha + "'}"
                , success: function (data, status) {
                    var txtHValue = $("#email");
                    var valoresID;
                    var arrCookie = [];
                    var arrLoginStatus = [];
                    var arrUsuarioID = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                        var item = JSON.stringify(data.d[i]["ID"]);

                        arrCookie.push(data.d[i]["Cookie"]);
                        arrLoginStatus.push(data.d[i]["LoginStatus"]);
                        arrUsuarioID.push(data.d[i]["UsuarioID"]);
                    }


                    switch (parseInt(arrLoginStatus)) {
                        case 0:
                            alert("Usuario Não Encontrado");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            alert("UsuarioAtivo");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            txtHValue.focus();
                            $("#msgErro").text("Necessario preencher os campos corretamentes");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            alert("SenhaValida");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            alert("UsuarioEncontrado");
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            var list = $.cookie("example", "" + arrCookie);
                            alert(list);

                            break;
                        case 8:
                            alert("UsuarioDuplicado");
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            alert("ChaveLicencaNaoLocalizada");
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            alert("LicencaExpirada");
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            alert("ExcessaoGenerica");
                            break;
                        case 16:
                            alert("LogonExpirado");
                            break;

                    }

                }
                , error: function (xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
                    //Caso ocorra algum erro:
                    $('.alert').html('Ocorreu um erro');
                }
            });

        });
    });
```